# AVG detecting my App as Malware

Tags: android, bluetooth, antivirus

I'm testing my app on a Nexus 7 and a Samsung Galaxy S4, and I'm going to test the behaviour on a Galaxy S2. I installed AVG AntiVirus (free version) from the Play Store - tablet version(Nexus 7) and the mobile version on the S4.

On my S4 AVG tells me that my app is detected as malware - but on the tablet it is detected as 'safe'. After some research, I found this [XML Parser triggers AV Alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890512/xml-parser-triggers-av-alert) SO thread. I use an AsyncTask to connect to a device via Bluetooth - showing a Snackbar as long as it is searching for new devices. I use the permissions for BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN.

To verify and test this issue with AVG mobile, I downloaded BluetoothChat from the sample in Android Studio and installed it on my S4 - with the same result, it is detected as Malware. So it seems to be a problem of AVG mobile AntiVirus or because I installed it from Android studio?
When I click on 'info' it opens a avgthreatlabs.com site on the browser, which tells me there is active adware in the package 'com.example.android.bluetoothchat', same happens with my app.
I use no ads.

Does someone know a workaround, or what went wrong? I don't want my app users to be confused by this issue.

I haven't found a appropiate communication or feedback link on the AVG website. Should I simply contact the Technical Support?

edit: I found the "report false detection" on the AVG website, I'm reporting the BluetoothChat example for now. :)

Sorry for my writing mistakes, or if the question is not appropiate for stackoverflow.

Comment: are you using any ad sdk or third party library?

Comment: There are no ads, but I am required to use several external libraries (which are on github and used by many others, or are from well known companies, so I expect no issues there.)Because of this I tested the BluetoothChat App with no changes, which gave me the same problem. :/

Comment: then this could be AVG issue

Comment: I fear so. I tried to commit the BluetoothChat example via [Report a false detection](http://www.avg.com/submit-sample) on AVG, but a mail came back, saying that the message recipient is no longer employed by AVG. So much for that,

Comment: Have you tried sending you apkto this link http://www.avg.com/submit-sample ?

Comment: Yes, I used this form to check it, look above. :) I updated AVG on my S5 and now it doesn't detect it anymore. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved after I updated the AVG App on my phone, so apparently it was an issue from their side.